# La question « C'est où...? » est-elle correcte ?

Tags: questions

J'ai entendu la phrase interrogative :

> C'est où Paul ?

Est-ce correct grammaticalement ?
S'agit-il d'une question familière ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S'il s'agit d'une question posée à Paul, c'est du français parlé courant mais il manque une virgule :

> C'est où, Paul ?

Il existe une forme intermédiaire :

> Où est-ce que c'est, Paul ?

et la forme soutenue équivalente est :

> Où est-ce, Paul ?

---

Si c'est une variante de *où est Paul*, la phrase est incorrecte et improbable de la bouche d'un francophone dont c'est la langue maternelle. *Ce* ne peut pas désigner une personne dans cette question mais uniquement une chose. Il est donc quand même possible d'entendre cette phrase si Paul désigne par exemple un commerce, comme on pourrait dire, *C'est où, Madame Tussauds ?* et pas *Elle est où, Madame Tussauds ?*

Pour demander où est Paul, les formes, du français parlé courant au plus soutenu, sont :

> Il est où, Paul ?
>
> Où il est, Paul ?
>
> Où est-ce qu'il est, Paul ?
>
> Où est Paul ?

Avec *c'est où*, il existe aussi une phrase idiomatique :

> C'est où, **chez** Paul ?

L'oubli du *chez* est incorrect mais plausible, en particulier si une pause marquée est présente ou si la question est posée par un enfant.

Comment: Merci encore.  J'aurais dû être plus clair. Ce n'est pas une question posée à Paul mais elle concerne Paul comme variante de << Où est Paul ? >>.

Comment: Êtes-vous sûr que le "Paul" en question n'est pas plutôt l'enseigne de restauration rapide ?

Comment: @Cocoduf C'est exactement ce à quoi je fais allusion lorsque j'écris *désigne un commerce*.

Comment: @Cocoduf Non, il ne s'agit pas d'un tel enseigne. C'est, comme j'ai indiqué à un commentaire, une question posée par quelqu'un qui voulait trouver Paul (personne). Mais, cette question fausse venait de la bouche d'un écolier d'une classe CM1. Donc, il aura le temps et l'occasion pour apprendre le correct:-)!

Comment: @dimitris Si la phrase a été prononcée par un enfant, il s'agit certainement de la dernière proposition que je viens d'ajouter à ma réponse.